# Bouncy Castle File Encryption open() method

Tags: java, file, encryption, bouncycastle

We are using bouncy castle library for file encryption. To do this, we need to use `PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.java` -> `.open(OutputStream out, byte[] buffer)` method.

Is there any criteria based on which we can decide on what should be the buffer size we should pass? Is there any standard for this? What parameters should be considered to pass the size of `byte[]` buffer

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The API doc seems to answer the question: https://borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/pg/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.html#open(java.io.OutputStream,%20byte[]) The size does not matter. It's used as buffer by the stream implementation. And only a size power of 2 is used.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for your answer. I also agree that size doesn't matter, but somehow I need to come-up with some valid answer regarding why we have used that specific number. I have used `65535` as `byte[]` size

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So I found the answer. So the number **65536** `new byte[1 << 16]` is a standard given by Bouncy Castle itself. Here is a reference link:
[Bouncy Castle API reference](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.java)